# Jaydata WebSql Provider with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jaydata

I've been using jaydata with TypeScript against an OData store as described here: http://jaystack.com/blog/typescript-meets-odata-with-the-help-of-jaydata-and-jaysvcutil.

Now, I'm trying to extend the application to use a local store as well (say, webSql) but it appears the typescript declaration file only allows for an OData context to be instantiated. How can I use the declaration file while targeting a different storage provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work for JayData. Sorry for the late reply.
In JayData we have a "virtual" provider called 'local'. It hides the different local storage technologies the different browsers support, so you don't have to worry about it and write code for IndexedDB, WebSQL and HTML5.localStorage. Just write it once and it will work.

All you have to do is to change the parameters of the service, like this:

```
var mydatabaseService = new mydatabase.mydatabaseService({
    name: 'local',
    databaseName: 'myitems'
});
```

There are a few things to be careful about:
-string primary keys are not supported (not by JayData but by the stores)
-if you want navigation properties then currently it is only supported by sqLite so you must use it explicit (name: 'sqLite' instead of name: 'local') and sqlite can not be found in every device. We will implement navigation in other stores soon.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I did this, now but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to instantiate a local context and use it with the entities auto-generated from my OData metadata. It only seems to work with the oData context.

Comment: I tried it before I answered and it works. Do you use the latest JayData? Is there anything on the console?

Comment: Do you load the provider manually or with onReady()? If manually then include the necessary provider, but I suggest autoloading it.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I get the following error message: 'Cannot call method 'addMany' of undefined '

Comment: Hi Gabor, I discovered that if I add a script reference to the provider file (indexedDb), the original error goes away but I get a new one: ' No valid key found!'. Any clues?

Comment: I think your context is not ready. How do you initialize your context ? Please provide snippets.

Comment: Thanks, Gabor. This is the way I initialize the context: var fuchsiaLocal = new QueryModelContext({
    name: 'webSql',
    databaseName: '1MyTodoDatabase'
}); I just realized what the issue was: My entities were not using integer IDs. The errors disappeared when I changed to webSql. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hijacking the OData type definition does work. However we are into to support standard TypeScript class definition as the means of defining local/remote types and context types. Expect it a week after TypeScript generics support is made available by MS (hope it's not too far)

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of stating the obvious: you could create your own `d.ts` declaration file, or edit the one you have been using, or see if there is one here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: These d.ts files are dynamic - or more precise to say is that they are specific to a database. It's unlikely to find them on DefinitelyType. jaydata.d.ts is another question, were into the submission process, since we will provide a d.ts for JayData that covers most of the funcitonality including the typesystem

Comment: Yes, fair enough - I just wanted to provide as many options as possible in regard to finding d.ts files.