# Jaydata - Typescript

Tags: typescript, jaydata

I use jaysvcutil to compile OData $metadata and create JayDataContext.js and it's really awesome but I use Typescript and I don't wanna use import/export syntax in typescript and other third party tools such as requirejs or systemjs ,...
jaysvcutil make JayDataContext.d.ts and it's module is only importable in typescript!
how can I compile JayDataContext.d.ts and use it's declaration file without import syntax ?

Comment: +1  Did you figure out how to make this work? I'm trying to use JayData 1.5.6 and so far have not been able to make it work. I've used earlier versions without seeing this type of issue.

Comment: I've got a sample code on github and I'm gonna developing and add some  more professional features.
you can see a simple project of odata-jaydata here
https://github.com/Alikhll/Implement-Odata-JayData

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jaydata WebSql Provider with Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683236/jaydata-websql-provider-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

you can use roslyn api to generate code yourself and of course you should create all needed typescript declarations too.
as you know you can use reflection to implement this feature but it would be in runtime, but roslyn make u sure to have all generated code in each build.

Comment: Please add some code and references and broaden your answer.